# Making backup with batch file - copy to the same subdirectory but on another drive

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I made my batch file that allows me to make automatic backup particular types of files from harddrive into flashdrive. Now my script copy all files into one folder.

I want it to copy files to the same subdirectory as origin like in example below:

form 
C:/**vacation_photos_2017**/pic1.jpg 
to 
E:/BackUpScript/BackUp/**vacation_photos_2017**/pic1.jpg

Can anyone help me with this?

My code looks like this:

```
SET FileSizeMin=20000
SET ExcludeList=%ExcludeList%%~d0\BackUpScript\exclude_list.txt
SET BackUpDir=%BackUpDir%%~d0\BackUpScript\BackUp

if exist %ExcludeList% del "%ExcludeList%"
echo.> %ExcludeList%
echo \Filmy\>> "%ExcludeList%"
echo \Seriale\>> "%ExcludeList%"

for %%d in (C:\ D:\) do (
    PUSHD %%d
    for /f "delims=" %%F in ('Dir /B/S/A *.jpg *.jpeg *.nef *.dng *.mp4 *.mov *.wmv *.avi *.3gp *.3g2 *.gif') do if %%~zF GTR %FileSizeMin% (xcopy /s/h/y/c /exclude:%ExcludeList% "%%F" "%BackUpDir%\")
    POPD
)
del "%ExcludeList%"
exit 0
```

[EDIT]

Ok, I have rewrite the script ussing Robocopy, it works as I want to (code below) but...
Afret batch script is done the main **BackUp3** folder (where script copied files) is hidden by a script. Script is hidding direcory in the way I cannot unhide (I dont know why).

Why this batch script is hidding my BackUp directory? Why I cannot unhide it by checking "show hidden files" in Folder Options?

```
SET BackUpDir=%~d0\VisualStudio\ArchitectureExplorer\BackUpDir3

for %%d in (E:\ F:\ G:\ H:\ I:\) do (
    if exist %%d (
    robocopy %%d %BackUpDir% *.jpg *.jpeg *.mp4 *.mov *.wmv *.avi *.3gp *.3g2 *.gif /MIN:20000 /s /W:15 /XD %%dFilmy %%dSeriale )
)
exit 0
```

Comment: You should look at using ROBOCOPY

Comment: OK.. but how to change the code using robocopy instead of xcopy to do what I want to? Simple changing xcopy to robocopy didnt work.

Comment: `RoboCopy` would certainly allow you to include the `/MIN:20000` option although the `/XF` option would need to be built from your `Exclude_List.txt` so there'd probably be no real benefit to you.

Comment: @alzajac, please delete your answer after [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49086285/edit), with its content as an update.